# Create table failed in HBase 1.4.9

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I want to create Demo table, for example, named Teacher and specify the number of versions that the table can store, I write the statement like this:

```
hbase(main):052:0> create 'Teacher', {NAME => 'username',VERSIONS => 2}
An argument ignored (unknown or overridden): username
An argument ignored (unknown or overridden): VERSIONS

ERROR: Table must have at least one column family
```

but I got the error like above, I don't know how to fix this problem, can you give me some instructions?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to create the teacher table with a username column family? I don't know why you would do that, personally I would just create a 'cf1' column family and then a username column, but it depends on your use case.

That being said, you're having troubles because that feature is not available in the version of HBase you're using.

```
help 'create'
create 'Teacher', 'username'
```

But again, I would do:

```
create 'teacher', 'cf1' # use a lowercase table name and a single column fam
put 'teacher', 'teacher-1', 'cf1:username', 'teacher1-username'
```